# UNIX_TIMESTAMP giving null

Tags: pyspark

Using spark-sql to run the below code.

select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(cast(5300 as string),'yyDDD'))

This returns null in spark but the same code gives output in hive.

Comment: i don't think you need `unix_timestamp` as that converts string representation of a ts to epoch. target format should be part of `from_unixtime`.

Comment: @samkart This did not work. The code which I sent is working for most of the records hut failing only for couple of records.